# Cannot assign to a property: 'class' is a 'let' constant

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm trying to update a property on a service that is defined as `let subscriber: SubscriberContextProviding` in the `WatchlistViewModel` by simply setting it directly like so:

```
subscriber.watchlist = watchlist
```

relevant subscriber definition:

```
final class Subscriber: SubscriberContextProviding {
  var watchlist = [String]()
}
```

however I get an error saying: `Cannot assign to property: 'subscriber' is a 'let' constant`
. The subscriber service is declared as a `let` and is initialised in the client `init`.
here is the relevant protocol part & `init`.

```
protocol SubscriberContextProviding {
  var watchlist: [String] { get set }
}

class WatchlistViewModel: NSObject {
  let subscriber: SubscriberContextProviding

  init(subscriber: SubscriberContextProviding){
    self.subscriber = subscriber
    super.init()
  }
}
```

however If I change the protocol from the one above to

```
protocol SubscriberContextProviding {
  func set(watchlist: [String])
}
```

and I simply define the function in the `subscriber` as

```
func set(watchlist: [String]){
  self.watchlist = watchlist
}
```

and instead of setting the property directly now using the function like so

```
subscriber.set(watchlist: watchlist)
```

works no problem. **Why the first approach doesn't work while the latter one does as the result is the same of both approaches?**

Comment: You've ommited the declaration of the type that conforms to `SubscriberContextProviding`. I presume it's a class? You should put the enclosing type back around your method, for clarity.

Comment: @Alexander yes the subscriber is a class. Well the type is super simple, it implements the watchlist property simply as var watchlist = [String]()

Comment: Edit that into your question, please.

Comment: @Alexander corrected. I think I know the answer already, its because if you call a function instead of directly setting the property from within the client object, then `subscriber` itself will modify the watchlist property & not the calling object, as such it still can be a `let`

Comment: That's not quite it. I'm writing up an answer atm, hang tight. Also, please put the free-flaoting `init(subscriber:)` and `set(watchlist:)` functions in their proper context, also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "issue" (though it's not an issue, really) is that you haven't restricted `SubscriberContextProviding` to being a class-bound protocol (with `: AnyObject`).

`let subscriber: SubscriberContextProviding` is declaring that your `subscriber` variable with contain an existential of any object whose type conforms to `SubscriberContextProviding`. Since that protocol isn't class-bound, it's possible that the concrete value you're dealing with is a value type (tuple, struct or enum), for which mutations are only allowed on mutable `var` variables. This existential is itself a value type, and abides the same rules of only allowing mutations on `var` variables.

Thus, you must either:

1. Declare `SubscriberContextProviding` as class-bound:

   ```
   protocol SubscriberContextProviding: AnyObject { ... }
   ```

   or
2. Keep your protocol as-is, but make your `subscriber` variable mutable, to account for the possibility that it contains a value type.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your protocol:

```
protocol SubscriberContextProviding: AnyObject{
  var watchlist: [String] { get set }
}
```